# Distributional derivative of absolute value function

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory, weak-derivatives

I'm tying to understand distributional derivatives. That's why I'm trying to calculate the distributional derivative of $|x|$, but I got a little confused.

I know that a weak derivative would be $\operatorname{sgn}(x)$, but not only I'm not finding that one in my calculations, I ended up with a wrong solution and in my other attempt I got
stuck pretty quickly.

Could someone tell me where my error in reasoning occurs or what I missed?

#### First attempt

$$
(T_{|x|}(\phi))' = T_{|x|'}(\phi)
=\int_{\mathbb{R}_+} \phi(x) dx - \int_{\mathbb{R}_-} \phi(x) dx = const.
$$

#### Second attempt

$$
(T_{|x|}(\phi))' = -T_{|x|}(\phi') = -\int_\mathbb{R} |x| \phi'(x) dx
=-\int_{\mathbb{R}_+} x \phi'(x) dx + \int_{\mathbb{R}_-} x \phi'(x) dx
$$

Comment: I have no idea what you are doing in your first attempt. Your second attempt is the right idea, but somehow you have replaced $\phi'$ by $\phi$ which is incorrect.

Comment: Oh thx sry that was a typo, I corrected it. I know the first attempt isn't a good one, but why does a lead me to a wrong answer?

Comment: Use integration by parts to evaluate the two integrals and then write as a single integral with the appropriate function (which you already know).

Comment: I am - to coin a phrase, with apologies to @copper.hat - talking through my hat, but even your first answer gives $\def \S{{\rm sgn}}\S(x)$:
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}_+} \phi(x) dx - \int_{\mathbb{R}_-} \phi(x) dx = \int_{\mathbb R}\S(x)\phi(x) \,dx.$$

Answer (score 10):

Given a test function $\phi$, the goal is to rewrite $-\int |x|\phi'(x)\,dx$ so that it has $\phi$ in it instead of $\phi'$. Split into two integrals over positive and negative half-axes; then integrate by parts. The result: 
$$
\int_{-\infty}^0 x\phi'(x)\,dx - \int_0^{\infty} x\phi'(x)\,dx
 = -\int_{-\infty}^0  \phi(x)\,dx + \int_0^{\infty} \phi(x)\,dx 
= \int_\mathbb{R} \operatorname{sgn}x \,\phi(x)\,dx
$$
which establishes the claim $|x|'=\operatorname{sgn}x$.

It's difficult to evaluate your attempted solutions, because they contain no words, and no steps that I can recognize as integration by parts.